# How to make the data of my angles appear in a degree form?

Tags: python, numpy, spyder, physics, projectile

I'm simulating projectile motion with python and there's one thing I need help with. As I use `plt.legend()` to show the angles corresponded to each lines(on the upper right corner of my graph), they appear in a radian form. How do I convert them to make them appear in an angle form, like `30 degree`, `60 degree` etc?

The graph:

[image: The graph of my projectile motion]

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math 

#theta=pi/3
V=38.5 #speed
t=np.arange(0,19,0.1)

angle = math.pi/12
angle_list=[]

while angle < math.pi/2:
    x=V*np.cos(angle)*t
    y=V*np.sin(angle)*t+(0.5*-9.8*t**2)
    plt.ylim([0,80])
    plt.xlim([0,170])
    print(x,y)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    angle_list.append(angle)
    angle+=math.pi/12
    
    
plt.xlabel("range")
plt.ylabel("height")
plt.title('Projectile Motion With Multiple Angles')
plt.legend(angle_list)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you could just transform the radian to degree like ```degree_list = [radian / math.pi * 180 for radian in angle_list]```, then ```plt.legend(degree_list)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.rad2deg`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rad2deg.html) or do the multiplication yourself:

```
angle_list.append(np.rad2deg(angle))
```

OR

```
angle_list.append(angle * 180.0 / np.pi)
```

`np.rad2deg` is equivalent to [`np.degrees`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.degrees.html).

You can format your angles by adding them to the legends as formatted strings. For example, since your angles are all multiples of 15 degrees, you don't need any decimal places:

```
angle_list.append(rf'{np.rad2deg(angle):.0f}$\degree$')
```

The result:

[image]